# How to use result of FileTransform task within contianer build task in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I am attemting to replace my secret variables inside appsetting.json file by FileTransform task in Azure pipeline and afterwards use the result of that task to build a container.

```
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: FileTransform
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyApp'
    fileType: 'json'
    targetFiles: 'appsettings.json'



- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: digital-ocean-docker
    repository: $(imageRepository)
    buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    command: build
    dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
    tags: $(Build.BuildId)



FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000

FROM node:lts-buster-slim AS node_base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
COPY --from=node_base . .
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyApp
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

I cant exactly figure out why when i run COPY . . in docker file old appsettings.json is used? or is it because FileTransform place transformed file somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed.

Reason was i had a section in appsetting.json named build which is a "safe" property which cannot be used in azure pipelines